# wso2 resolve missing dependencies

Tags: java, wso2

I've successfully managed to run the code from this tutorial, using carbon studio, maven and m2e on my GReg server on localhost:

http://www.smartjava.org/content/access-wso2-registry-programatically

Now I want to create create a new Artefact, following the documentation at
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Configurable+Governance+Artifacts+with+API

The problem is that I don't know which libraries to include for those imports and my built with maven project doesn't have them. (I use the pom.xml from the first tutorial)

```
import org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.GenericArtifactManager;
import org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.generic.dataobjects.GenericArtifact;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was happens due to unavailability of governance API dependency. Please add below dependency to your pom.xml

```
`<dependency>
 <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
 <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.governance.api</artifactId>
 <version>4.0.3</version>
 </dependency>`
```